# Joining two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I want to add data from table b in table a but unfortunately full outer join do not work in mysql . I have also tried union but it is throwing errors because my statement has group by and order by keyword

```
SELECT COUNT( ReviewedBy ) AS TotalReviews, OrganizationId, SUM( Rating ) AS TotalStars, COUNT( Rating ) AS TotalRatings, (
       SUM( Rating ) / COUNT( Rating )
          ) AS AverageRating
        FROM  `tbl_reviews` 
      WHERE ReviewType =  'shopper'
      AND ReviewFor =  'org'
       AND OrganizationId
               IN (

           SELECT OrganizationId
         FROM tbl_organizations
         WHERE CategoryID =79
          )
        GROUP BY OrganizationId
        ORDER BY AverageRating DESC
```

[This is what i'm getting from the above statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4ixM.png)

I want to get organizationId 21 data in the result but i'm not getting result because it's not present in 'tbl_review' table
[click here to see the table b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MpBY.png)

How can i get Desired result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a FULL, but a LEFT join:

```
SELECT COUNT( ReviewedBy ) AS TotalReviews, o.OrganizationId, 
   SUM( Rating ) AS TotalStars, COUNT( Rating ) AS TotalRatings, 
   (SUM( Rating ) / COUNT( Rating )) AS AverageRating
FROM tbl_organizations AS o
LEFT JOIN `tbl_reviews` AS r
  ON o.OrganizationId = r.OrganizationId
 AND ReviewType =  'shopper' -- conditions on inner table 
 AND ReviewFor =  'org'      -- must be moved to ON
WHERE CategoryID =79
GROUP BY o.OrganizationId
ORDER BY AverageRating DESC
```

Why don't you use `AVG` instead of `SUM/COUNT`?

Comment: will use AVG from now 
and 
Thanks dude ... 
You saved my hours

Comment: @SumitBhatia . . . If this answers your question, then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
from organization
left outer join tbl_reviews
on organization.ID = tbl_reviews.organization is
```

for your where clause?  I don't think you need a full outer join in this case... A left outer join should do